# Google Data API Integration - Which Authentication Model?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-data-api, google-authentication

I am in the processing of developing a web application which will integrate directly with a Google Calendar associated with a specific Google account. The account being accessed by the Google Data API is not likely to change, so I'm unsure what the most appropriate account authentication method is going to be.

I've reviewed the options avilable and it would seem that [AuthSub](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html#AuthSub) and [OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html#OAuth) are inappropriate as I will not be logging users into their own account- only displaying and updating a fixed account. The other options available are [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html#ClientLogin) and [Gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html#Gadgets) authentication. Of all of them, ClientLogin seems the best fit, but the documentation states that it is intended for installed applications. While the web application I am developing is not specifically an installed application, it closely mirrors one in this scenario- which is why I think ClientLogin makes the most sense.

Which Google authentication option would be the best fit in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html it seems to me that OAuth is the most secure way to achieve your goals. Google recommends OAuth or AuthSub over ClientLogin for Web Applications. In addition using OAuth and AuthSub prevents your application from ever having control of the users email and password meaning you dont need to take the extra steps to protect and update the information. Between OAuth and AuthSub, OAuth is more universally adopted, and more secure due to the fact that requests are signed. Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** So I misunderstood exactly what your application was doing, if you are only using your google account any method of authentication is probably fine, that said google recommends OAuth or AuthSub for web apps. However the important thing to find out about OAuth and AuthSub is what the life of the token is. If there is no way to make the token last for a long time (months, years) then I would try to use ClientLogin, because then your application will always be able to login to the account. As a side note however for security I would recommend you NOT use your primary google account for the application instead create a second account and simply share the calendar with your primary account, that way if you application was compromised you would not lose your primary google account.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Was I mistaken in my understanding that OAuth implementations are a better fit for scenarios where a user is going to be identifying their own account with Google and editing their personal data? My application is going to be driving a Google calendar and users of my application will be indirectly adding data to *my* calendar.

Comment: Check out this link: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Auth. Interestingly they recommend AuthSub although if possible OAuth seems like a better method to me.See my edit above.

Comment: based on that text, I'd say I fit neither descriptor because my application is a single-user web application: 'If your client is a standalone single-user "installed" client (such as a desktop application), then you should use the ClientLogin system; if your client is a multi-user web application client, then you should use the AuthSub system.'